# Filter or Find Finder Items Using Variable

Tags: finder, applescript, automator

In the `Filter Finder Items` and `Find Finder Items` actions, Automator lets you type out criteria for what your looking for like:

**Folder Name Contains:** (Manually Insert Text Here)

Here is an example image of "AnchorFile" being the typed criteria:

[image: Example Action]

Is there anyway to pass a variable onto the filter?

I have tried to put a `Get Value of Variable` action before the filter/find in the hopes of being able to use the variable as the search criteria. Similar to this workflow:

[image: Filter w/ Variable??]

The goal is to find the "XXXXX_Workers Compensation" folder on my computer using only a `variable` and `filter/find` Actions

I hope this is clearer than a previous post I made as I am a newbie in the Applescript/Automator world.

If we can get this "pass a variable to filter/find" thing to work, it would effectively:

- Create a **foldername** from a **filename**,
- Then input that **foldername** into the search bar of **Finder** to bring up the folder in Finder.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: RE: "I hope this is clearer than a previous post I made" -- Sorry to say, but no, it is not any clearer than the now deleted previous post [Using Finder Items as filter criteria in Automator](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415349/using-finder-items-as-filter-criteria-in-automator?noredirect=1#comment583041_415349)  (Need 10,000 rep to see the contents of this link, or be the author.)

Comment: The text field in that action does not accept variables (not all of them do), so you will need to use something else.

Comment: @user3439894 What could I have done to present the issue more clearly?

Comment: @red_menace you were right. I needed to switch out `Filter/Find Finder Items` for `Spotlight` I think increased functionality is needed to use variables as inputs in the criteria section of these actions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to do a `spotlight search` instead of `Filter/Find Finder Items` in order to use a string to find the folder by its name alone (Without path).

I also did not need to store the filename as a variable in order for me to accomplish this final workflow but spotlight can use a variable that is a string to search I found out.

Here is my final workflow. [image: WorkFlow]

EXPLANATION:

(`Get Specified Finder Items` and `Get Folder Contents` were in place for testing within Automator)

1. A file being added to a folder called "WCCalcs" triggers the workflow.
2. Steps 1-2 (`Filter Finder Items` and `Set Value or Variable`):

   Singles out our new file which is a pdf and saves it in a variable called 'MovingFile'.
   It will always look like "#####_WCCalcs_YYYY"

   - with "#####" being a 5-digit number
   - and "YYYY" being the current year
3. Steps 3-4 (`Get PDF Metadata` and `Run AppleScript`):

   Takes the first 5 characters of the file name and adds it to a string and this creates the folder name we need becoming "#####_Workers Compensation" (See AppleScript.)
4. Steps 5-8 (`Spotlight`,`Get Folder Contents`, `Filter Finder Items`, `Set Value of Variable`):

   Uses the newly created folder name to do a spotlight search as well as  filters down to a destination folder which we stored in a variable called 'Destination.
5. Steps 9-10 (`Get Value of Variable` and `Move Finder Items`):

   Calls `MovingFile` variable and moves it to the `Destination` folder

Thanks for your help @red_menace it caused me to think outside of what I was trying to do.

Comment: While this answer may work for for you, nonetheless as presented it's of little to no value to anyone else because all but one of the _actions_ are collapsed and we cannot tell how any of the remaining _actions_ are configured. BTW If more then one _file_ is received in the **Folder Action** then as coded **Run AppleScript** _action_ it will fail.

Comment: @user3439894 only 1 file will arrive at a time so that should not be a problem for me.  The main question that this answers is 'finding a directory without needing the entire file path' just the one unique directory.  How can I modify the explanation to make it more useful to others? also i would've loved to work with you to modify your answer to make the workflow quicker.